# My images won't display on Safari with website Netlify.app

Tags: html, css, image, web, netlify

I'm building a portfolio website and I'm trying to add images to "see my works" section of my website.
i have 3 images --> image-1, image-2 and image-3. these works fine at my own computer but when i try to display my site in mobile, images won't display.

[see my temporary website](https://hopeful-hodgkin-b1ff09.netlify.app/)

see the "Some examples of pages that I have done" section of page.

[**Screenshot from my phone.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgb1R.jpg)

this is the html for each image:

```html
<!-- 01 -->
<figure class="port-item"> 
    <img src="./images/img-1.jpg" alt="Image - 1">  <!-- Problem here!-->
    <figcaption class="port-desc">
        <p>Project Title</p>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-accent">See Live</a>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

[See images I use on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wdMd.png)

More HTML and CSS :

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.portfolio h2 {
    margin: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10vh 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}



.port-item {
    position: relative;
}
.port-desc {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.port-desc p{
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .port-items {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15em,1fr));
    }
    
    
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .port-item {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .port-desc {
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transition: transform .4s ease;
    }
    .port-item:hover .port-desc {
        transform: translateY(0);
        
}
}
```

```html
    <section class="portfolio">
    <h2>Some examples of pages that I have done</h2>
        <div class="port-items">
            <!-- Itee -> 01 -->
            <figure class="port-item">
                <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="Image - 1">
                <figcaption class="port-desc">
                    <p>Project Title</p>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-accent">See Live</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>

            <!-- Itee -> 02 -->
            <figure class="port-item">
                <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="Image - 2">
                <figcaption class="port-desc">
                    <p>Project Title</p>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-accent">See Live</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>

            <!-- Itee -> 03 -->
            <figure class="port-item">
                <img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="Image - 3">
                <figcaption class="port-desc">
                    <p>Project Title</p>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-accent">See Live</a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
</section>
```

**Note: my index.html and images folder are in the same folder.**

[**My folders**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYOv9.png)

Comment: Could you show us more html and css, please ?

Comment: of course. I added above

Comment: Your code seems to be pretty clear. Problem should come from your file path. Is your images directory by the root ?

Comment: Yes ,my html files and images folder are in the same folder.

Comment: Then you should write the path like : `src="images/img-2.jpg` so without the first: `/`. Try like that and if I am write I will post an answer

Comment: i republished the website unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Actualy it seems to work fine `src="images/img-2.jpg` as show in my answer. Just try to clear your browser cache sometimes

Comment: When I minimized the Browser, I still saw the images on your site. Clear your phone cache out.

Comment: I'm calling code.jpg and intro.jpg from css/styles.css . my html file is on the same path as the images folder.

Comment: @Arshia I guess you just need to clear your cache to get the result as shown.

Comment: I added a new image above (Screenshot from my phone) please check that. in my computer i can see my images but at mobile images are not displayed. that's my problem.

Comment: @Arshia is your phone an iphone ? Because on Safari it does not show the image neither

Comment: How can i fix it ? @MaxiGui

Comment: @Arshia Please check my answer, based on my research it seems to be a bug from netlify.app and some js. Check my answer but I would recommand you to contact them directly.

Comment: @MaxiGui I think you’re right that’s the only explanation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following our discussion in comment, as your images folder is in the same folder with your file, you are supposed to write it without the first **/** so as follow :

```
<img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="Image - 3">
```

**If you must change the path of your image, think about clearing the cache of your browser.**

You get more information about the rules to manage path here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Your result: [image]

**EDIT**

After my research it seems that images are not shown on safari because of a bug between netlify.app and Safari, please check this link:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658613

So normaly, it should not be a problem if you would deploy a true website.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

try this `<img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="Image - 3">` it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your Hero Image shows and the url is `../images/intro.jpg` but all your figure images have `./images/intro.jpg`

does that make a difference?

Comment: That's a background-image that i add from css. my css files in styles folder

Comment: okay, that makes sense. 

if your images are in a directory at the same level as the html file then you shouldn't need a / just images/FILE.jpg but if that does work you could try going up a level ../images/file.jpg. This will work if you are at the root of you site I would think. 

Remember to clear cache though, mobile devices are hard to clear so maybe try change the directory name to img/FILE.jpg